# How to start applet in eclipse by providing eclipse with an html file?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, applet

I have written java applet programs under eclipse and run them with help of "run configuration" to provide applet parameters. I have also written a few html files containing <applet> </applet> tags. But I couldn't run applet under eclipse by submitting html files. I don't know how to set the run configuration in eclipse to open an html file with applet. I am looking for ideas to run applets under eclipse by providing eclipse with an html file.  I would be grateful, if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First follow Justins advice. The look at this link for understanding how to pass paramters to an applet thru html. http://www.brainjar.com/java/parameters/

Snippet from the site.

```
<applet code="MyApplet.class" width="300" height="100">
 <param name="background-color" value="#ffffff">
 <param name="foreground-color" value="#000000">
</applet>
```

Answer (score 3):

A new answer to your edited question.
Copied from the internet and updated by me to fit Eclipse Indigo:).

> First you will have to go to preferences in Window/Web Browser and set Eclipse to Use internal Web > browser.
>
> After that you can open the HTML file from the navigator tree using right click/Open With/Web Browser.

Comment: That doesn't handle the APPLET tag.  You're not answering the (edited?) question.

Answer (score 0):

Does the applet have a .jar file? If so you can put the .jar file and the HTML in the same folder, and then open the HTML file in a browser of your choice. It works for me. It's just a different way to open.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But I just want to start applet under eclipse by providing eclipse with an html file. I don't know how to set the run configuration in eclipse to open an html file with applet.