# Applet in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, applet

I am creating an Eclipse plug it. I have an applet that I wish to run in an Eclipse View. Is this possible? I know I cannot use Eclipse's internal browser because it will not run applets.

Comment: Maybe this will help ::http://stackoverflow.com/q/7179636/1085285

Comment: What do you mean by Eclipse view? Yes you can run an applet in eclipse. Just right click the java file and "Run as" applet.

Comment: I am creating a plugin for Eclipse. Eclipse breaks the panes in its window up a different views. Examples of a view are the outline, project view, etc. I need to have my applet appear in the view window when the user adds my plugin and opens the plugin view. I want very little if no user interaction to make this occur.